# Password Requirements when making an account with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

What are the requirements to avoid throwing the "auth/weak-password" error code on the `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`.

I would like to show the user the requirements so they don't have to throw the error several times on the way to create an account.

I have checked the firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

and stack overflow but have not found this info.

Comment: Firebase documentation is soooo poor, not sure why this basic thing is missed out

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only weakness test I'm aware of is length less than 6 characters:

> public final class FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException extends
>   FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException
>
> Thrown when using a weak password (less than 6 chars) to create a new
>   account or to update an existing account's password. Use getReason()
>   to get a message with the reason the validation failed that you can
>   display to your users.

Excerpted from [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException).