# Firebase Authentication: Password must contain capital letter

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My application is linked with firebase database and authentication.

When a user creates an account, the only requirements for the password are for it to be 6 characters. Is there anyway I can make the password more complex, such as make them have a capital letter and a number.

Can I do this from firebase directly, or do I need to do this from my code?

Comment: What have yu tried so far? Can you show us your code for the password

Comment: Yes you can certainly do that. It will be done on the front end side rather than at the backend side.
In your app you can write some string parsing methods that makes sure that the string contains a Capital letter and a number

Comment: If you want to do it from firebase directly you might want to use firebase rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function. It includes range 6-15 i.e. minimum 6 and maximum 15 characters.One Capital letter , One number respectively.

```
func isValidPasswordString(pwdStr:String) -> Bool {

    let pwdRegEx = "(?:(?:(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[-!@#$%&*ˆ+=_])|(?:(?=.*?[0-9])|(?=.*?[A-Z])|(?=.*?[-!@#$%&*ˆ+=_])))|(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[-!@#$%&*ˆ+=_]))[A-Za-z0-9-!@#$%&*ˆ+=_]{6,15}"

    let pwdTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", pwdRegEx)
    return pwdTest.evaluate(with: pwdStr)
}
```

This func will return true for valid password string

Comment: This will indeed force the users of the app to enter a password that matches the regular expression. But malicious users can extract the Firebase configuration data from the application, and then call the API themselves. They'd be bypassing this check, and thus be able to create users with passwords that don't match the regular expression. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45352865/209103) for an alternative solution that doesn't have this problem, but *does* require that you create a custom identity provider.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to configure Firebase Authentication's rules for password strength.

Also see

- [Password Requirements when making an account with firrebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530984/password-requirements-when-making-an-account-with-firrebase)
- [Firebase Password Validation allowed regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064248/firebase-password-validation-allowed-regex).

You can (and should ) restrict it from your code. But you can't prevent malicious users from bypassing this by calling the API directly.

If the password strength is a hard requirement for your app, consider implementing [custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth). This [example of custom username (instead of email) and password authentication](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/username-password-auth) might be helpful.