# Associated domains for automatic strong passwords in iOS with Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to setup automatic strong passwords with Firebase for iOS? My understanding is that an associated domain file needs to be added to the backend in order to enable this feature. I have not seen any documentation on whether this is possible in Firebase.

I really hope it is!!

Comment: There is no way to configure the password requirements of Firebase Authentication's built-in email/password provider. If you want control over the password requirements, you'll have to build your own provider. See my answer here for some links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45352865/209103

Comment: Hi Frank, This isn't about providing password strength, it's about a new feature added in iOS 12 that makes it super easy for iOS user's to create an account by having an automatic password generated and is a standard feature now in a fair amount of apps.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This feature fundamentally improves user security and their experience - https://www.raywenderlich.com/7162-ios-12-password-tools-improving-user-security-and-experience

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen perhaps I should make a feature request for it? as it something that I think a hell people would want.

Comment: What would Firebase Authentication do, where it relates to this feature? I scanned the article you linked, but it wasn't clear to me what the domain is actually "doing". What's its role in the password generation? I use Chrome's and Lastpass' password generator with many apps on Android and Mac, and I doubt the underlying (Firebase or other) apps know anything about that.