# Is there a way to set a password strength for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

```
 const connect = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).catch(function(error){

          if(error.code === 'auth/weak-password'){
          errmsg.style.display = 'block';
          errmsg.style.opacity = '1';
          errmsg.innerHTML= 'The password is too weak.';
      }
```

With the default setting, the requirement for password is 6 characters (letter/number). Is there a way to change this (Ex. require password to be letter-number combined)>

Answer (score 17):

**Update**: if your project is on Cloud Identify, you can now [set a password policy](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/password-policy).

---

Previous answer

The password strength of Firebase Authentication's email+password authentication is not configurable. If you want full control over the requirements, you can consider [implementing your own provider on top of Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

Also see:

- [Set Minimum Password Length Firebase Email & Password Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318198/set-minimum-password-length-firebase-email-password-authentication/36319652#36319652)
- [Enforce custom rules for passwords for Firebase Auth accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897741/enforce-custom-rules-for-passwords-for-firebase-auth-accounts)
- [Firebase Password Validation allowed regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064248/firebase-password-validation-allowed-regex)
- [Password Requirements when making an account with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530984/password-requirements-when-making-an-account-with-firrebase)

Comment: you may forget to include https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/password-policy as the last method, it is a feature in Google Cloud Identity, Which a new version of Firebase uses as a base for Firebase Authentication Module.

Comment: Also, you may take a look at the "Blocking Function" feature in Firebase Console if GCP Identity password policy is not enough. You can validate it to whatever you like like not having the same word as email, or such bad words or else. It will run before user creation so you may use it to create a database as well and validate the password. it use Firebase Cloud Function.

Answer (score 5):

my solution for this is, I **also** run firebase auth in the backend

I create functions that run validation and create user as callback

it works fine for me

update: I do not recommend this method

Comment: But what about reset password functionality from firebase?

Comment: You can customize the password reset process and handle your custom logic from there: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: Unfortunately, running a server just for the reset password form is quite an overhead for serverless apps, that is games in my case.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/product-comparison) you can [set up password policies](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/password-policy).
Since Firebase version 10.2.0 you can use [`validatePassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#validatepassword) to validate the password against the password policy configured for the project or tenant.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to resolve this issue is to use a function in your registration front end that enforces whatever password policy you need. Then you would only create a new Firebase account with that password once it meets the minimum requirements. To make it more dynamic make the function an API call.

Comment: If a user forgets the password and the new password will be reset with sendPasswordResetEmail() there might be a problem in case the password strength which is required for Firebase might not meet your policy. At least when the password input field is also validated against your security policy. In such a case the user would be locked out.

Comment: Why would you evaluate password complexity at authetnication time? That's just silly. It only makes sense to do so when you're setting it.

Comment: It is still not recommended because, with the token, a user still can call the Firebase native API to create the user instead of yours. you may need to follow Frank's first method to set the custom claim so it is safe cause Client SDK doesn't have this ability at all. The front end may only increase the UX but it is not safe at all. The best practice is to have both validation and the minimum is server only. 
Your API can work if you disable SDK user creation at the Firebase Console and only create the user via Admin SDK (Your API).

Answer (score 0):

I did it with my form when creating a user (Client Side Validation),
It could be also on the backend side, and as Laurent say you can use the validatePassword.

EX on Frontend using material-UI, inputProps (Form Submit!):

```
                        <TextField
                        id="password"
                        label="Password"
                        type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                        required
                        value={password}
                        tabIndex={2}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        // Password validation: minimum 8 characters, at least one uppercase letter and one number
                        inputProps={{
                            pattern: '(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}',
                            title: 'Password must contain at least 8 characters, including one uppercase letter and one number.',
                        }}
                        InputProps={{
                            endAdornment: (
                                <InputAdornment position="end">
                                    <IconButton tabIndex={-1}
                                        onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                                        edge="end"
                                    >
                                        {showPassword ? <EyeIcon /> : <EyeOff />}
                                    </IconButton>
                                </InputAdornment>
                            ),
                        }}
                    />
```